# xcode animation transition error

Tags: xcode, animation, transition

When i try setting my animation to 'push' from a view controller that has a navigation controller to a view controller without one or to a view controller with a navigation controller, this error pops up. but when i use the animation 'show' or 'show detail' they work perfectly fine. I have tried other methods to fix this by deleting the outlet segue with the exclamation mark but my outlet segues dont have any of those symbols showing up....

```
    2016-06-15 23:24:46.546 Travel_Log[667:9045] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UITextField): [<UITextField 0x7fe6e3759b90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
2016-06-15 23:24:49.922 Travel_Log[667:9045] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d35d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107d1edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x00000001069858c9 __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000106984bf5 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 848
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000106f6fc44 __66-[UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 1660
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106ee9630 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000106ee9433 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106ee96f7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001067a3a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106916e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106917143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106916263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010681699f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001068176d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001067c2dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010679c553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c5b301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c5122c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c506e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c500f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b683ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001067a1f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  Travel_Log                          0x0000000105ae8322 main + 114
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109a4e92d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: is it because i have linked the button to a navigation controller? Do i have to link it to the view controller?

Comment: it seems because i have more than one navigation controller in the storyboard...am i correct?